# Which android devices support the en_CA locale?

Tags: android, localization

Which android devices support the en_CA locale?

I have several devices including the Nexus S, Galaxy Nexus, Acer tablet, Galaxy Tab, Xoom, Droid X; and none of these devices have a user-selectable option for Canadian locales.  Are there any devices on the market that come with the option to select the en_CA locale?

Answer (score 1):

I think all Android *devices* should support en_CA, but it really depends on the ROM, which generally means it depends on what the OEM decided to put on there. I suspect that means that many of the devices you listed will in fact have Canadian locale support, but only if you buy them in Canada. I have an HTC Sensation with the [Virtuous Inquisition](http://www.virtuousrom.com/p/inquisition.html) 3.0 ROM that supports English (Canada), but I checked four stock US devices that I have sitting on my desk and none of them have it (they all have en-US and Spanish, one has Chinese as well).